# Meaning of forEach(function(tag) in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, couchdb

I came across the following code fragment in a [CouchDB book](http://books.couchdb.org/relax/design-documents/views).

```
function(doc) {
  doc.tags && doc.tags.forEach(function(tag) {
    emit(tag, 1);
  });
}
```

Can some one explain how does the function(tag) part works?

Thanks and regards,

raj

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is called an anonymous inline function expression. It creates a function and gives you a reference to it, similar to if you had written:

```
function emitTag(tag) {
    emit(tag, 1);
}
doc.tags && doc.tags.forEach(emitTag);
```

The `array.forEach` method calls the given function once for each of the items in `array` in order. It is a standard method in ECMAScript Fifth Edition and has been in many browsers for some time, but not JScript (IE). I am guessing couchdb takes care of that issue for you though.

Comment: Thanks every one for your nice answers and quick response :)

Comment: This is map function in CouchDB. That doesn't run in Browser. It runs on server in spidermonkey. So you can use any latest Javascript trick that spidermonkey supports

Comment: Ah, that makes sense then. Spidermonkey has supported the Fifth Edition Array methods for ages.

Answer (score 1):

```
function(tag) {...}
```

gets called "for each"  tag in "doc.tags" with the "tag" argument passed to the lambda function in question.

Answer (score 0):

`forEach` simply iterates over array and calls function you pass to it with every element it finds.

Be aware that not every browser support it, there's helper function `$.forEach` in jQuery, it is safer in terms of browser support.

Comment: As noted in the accepted answer, the JS engine is server side and suggesting a jQuery function is not only unnecessary, but also will not work.